# Jekyll-Chirpy does not run math as I need

Tags: html, jekyll, editor.md

I am trying to setup a new blog template, [jekyll chirpy](https://chirpy.cotes.page/), And oddly, the math is weird.

Like, the math parses great while in post, but in the preview It shows the LaTeX commands

Any idea on how to fix it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5CYC.png)

I am not sure, math is enabled and I also have

```
math: true
```

In the blogpost.md

Comment: I still need help, fwiw.